# Hoisting of non-atomic loads up through acquiring atomic loads

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, atomic

I was under the impression that memory loads could not be hoisted above an acquiring load in the C++11 memory model. However looking at the code that gcc 4.8 produces that only seems to be true for other atomic loads, not all of memory. If that's true and acquiring loads don't synchronize all memory (just `std::atomics`) then I'm not sure how it would be possible to implement general purpose mutexes in terms of std::atomic.

The following code:

```cpp
extern std::atomic<unsigned> seq;
extern std::atomic<int> data;

int reader() {
    int data_copy;
    unsigned seq0;
    unsigned seq1;
    do {
        seq0 = seq.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        data_copy = data.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        seq1 = seq.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    } while (seq0 != seq1);
    return data_copy;
}
```

Produces:

```
_Z6readerv:
.L3:
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR seq[rip]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR data[rip]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR seq[rip]
    cmp ecx, edx
    jne .L3
    rep ret
```

Which looks correct to me.

However changing data to be an `int` rather than `std::atomic`:

```cpp
extern std::atomic<unsigned> seq;
extern int data;

int reader() {
    int data_copy;
    unsigned seq0;
    unsigned seq1;
    do {
        seq0 = seq.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        data_copy = data;
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        seq1 = seq.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    } while (seq0 != seq1);
    return data_copy;
}
```

Produces this:

```
_Z6readerv:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR data[rip]
.L3:
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR seq[rip]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR seq[rip]
    cmp ecx, edx
    jne .L3
    rep ret
```

So what's going on?

Comment: If you rewrite atomic ops order to `load(rel); fence(acq);` in second version, does its output asm change?

Comment: @yoyjp Are you referring to the loading of `seq0`? If so then no, it doesn't affect the code generated at all.

Comment: No, I mentioned `seq1`. An "acquire fence" which has acquire semantics is consist of `seq1.load(relaxed) -> fence(acquire)` ops order, not `fence(acquire) -> seq1.load(relaxed)` in C++11 memory model. C++'s "fence" **only** influences _happens-before relationship_ between atomic operations or/and fences, it have **no** directly impact on non-atomic vars. In this point, C++'s "fence" is quite different from processor's/compiler's memory barrier instruction (like mfence of x86).

Comment: @yohjp Have a look at the edit I just made, it reduces the complexity a lot. Do you have a standards quote for "only influences happens-before relationship between atomic operations or/and fences" - if that's true then it's not possible to synchronize non-atomic data with these fences.

Comment: That sentence is not direct quote from C++11 standard, but result of my interpreting 29.8 [atomic.fences] and 1.10 [intro.multithread]. IMO "it's not possible to synchronize non-atomic data with these fences" (as you say), and synchronization for non-atomic data is attained with a combination of 'non-atomic + atomic ops' or 'non-atomic + atomic ops + atomic_fence'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why a load was hoisted above an acquire**

I've posted this on the [gcc bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57448) and they've confirmed it as a bug.

> > > the MEM alias-set of -1 (ALIAS_SET_MEMORY_BARRIER) is supposed to prevent this,
> > >       but PRE does not know about this special property (it should "kill" all refs
> > >       crossing it).

It looks like the [gcc wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/Optimizations/Details) has  a nice page about this.

> > > Generally, release is a barrier to sinking code, acquire is a barrier to hoisting code.

**Why this code is still broken**

As per [this paper](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2012/HPL-2012-68.pdf) my code is still incorrect, because it introduces a data race. Even though the patched gcc generates the correct code, it's still not proper to access `data` without wrapping it in `std::atomic`. The reason is that data races are undefined behavior, even if computations resulting from them are discarded.

An example courtesy of AdamH.Peterson:

```
int foo(unsigned x) {
    if (x < 10) {
        /* some calculations that spill all the 
           registers so x has to be reloaded below */
        switch (x) {
        case 0:
            return 5;
        case 1:
            return 10;
        // ...
        case 9:
            return 43;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here a compiler might optimise the switch into a jump table, and thanks to the if statement above would be able to avoid a range check. However if data races were not undefined behaviour then an second range check would be required.

Comment: The 2 are not incompatible.  Your code has a data race and the C++ standard says clearly (1.10 21) that your code is relying on undefined behavior.  The code IS incorrect (or at the very least missing the right synchronization to prove your point).  Once again, the hp paper makes this clear as well (the author is one of the architects of the c++11 memory model)
1.10 13 says that gcc is not allowed to do code hoisting.  If this happens on valid C++ code, it's a bug.
The whole point was that *if* there were no data race, the code generated would be correct (at least I dont see why not)

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin: I'm tempted to agree. The release sequence that's formed by the store and the load is just one component in the happens-before chain. The code would be correct with the second thread as posted if the first thread said something like `if (seq_copy == 2) { data_copy = data; }`. In that case `data = 2` *happens-before* the atomic store, which *synchronizes-with* the atomic load, which *happens-before* the `data_copy = data`. With the code as posted, access to `data` causes a race. (And the corrected code generates correct output for me, too.)

Comment: @GuillaumeMorin I realize you're correct now, I've amended my answer to help anybody else who sees this. It's a shame the waters were muddied by the fact that there was also a bug in gcc.

Comment: Your example is talking about two different triggers of undefined behavior.  If `data` is not atomic, reading it when there's a potential asynchronous writer results in a "data race", which gives undefined behavior, regardless of the division.  If you use atomics, locks, or some other mechanism to ensure no asynchronous writes, there's no undefined behavior despite `data` not being an atomic.  If `data` is a shared atomic, you may hit "integer math (divide-by-zero)"-type undefined behavior, despite it being atomic.  (However, if `data` is a local variable set from an atomic load, you're fine.)

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson That's true, I hope it's not too confusing, but I just wanted to provide some kind of reasoning for why the standards committee chose to make data races UB (the above being an example which would be very difficult to compile if they were allowed, because of the potential runtime trap). I'm afraid I'm never very satisfied with "that's just the rule", I like to understand why things are the way they are.

Comment: @jleahy, as with most UB, the big reason is to enable optimizations.  Without it, many previously valid optimizations become problemmatic.  Example: `int foo(unsigned x) { if (x<2) { /*...*/ switch (x) { case 0: return 5; case 1: return 10; } } return 0; }`.  The `switch` will likely be implemented with a jump table, but the jump table requires a bounds-check to avoid a wild jump.  If there's no data race, the optimizer can detect that the code has already done the bounds check and elide it.  Otherwise, it has to emit code for extra work that's usually (for some programs, always) redundant.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson That's a nice example, do you mind if I add it to my answer?

Comment: @jleahy, not at all.  If you do add it, you might tweak it a bit, though.  You could add more than just 2 cases.  (With only two cases, the optimizer probably won't use a jump table.)  And you could replace `/*...*/` with `/* some calculations that spill all the registers so x has to be reloaded below */`.  I didn't write it that way because of the length limit in comments, but in an answer it can be longer (and clearer).

Answer (score 1):

I do not think your atomic_thread_fence is correct.  The only C++11 memory model that works with your code would be seq_cst one.  But this is very expensive (you're going to get a full memory fence) for what you need.

The original code works and I think this is the best performance tradeoff.

EDIT based on your updates:

If you're looking for the formal reason why the code with a regular int is not working the way you'd like, I believe the very paper you quoted (http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2012/HPL-2012-68.pdf) gives the answer.  Look at the end of section 2.  Your code has the same problem as the code in Figure 1.  It has data races.  Multiple threads can do operations on the same memory on the regular int at the same time.  It it forbidden by the c++11 memory model, this code is formally not valid C++ code.

gcc expects the code to have no data race, i.e being valid C++ code.  Since there is no race and the code loads the int unconditionally, a load can be emitted anywhere in the body of the function.  So gcc is smart and it just emits it once since it is not volatile.  The conditional statement that usually goes hand in hand with an acquire barrier plays an important role in what the compiler will do.

In the formal slang of the standard, the atomic loads and the regular int loads are unsequenced.  The introduction for example of a condition would create a sequence point and would force the compiler to evaluate the regular int after the sequence point (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45c7a5d.aspx).  Then the c++ memory model would do the rest (i.e ensure the visibility by the cpu executing the instructions)

So neither of your statements are true.  You can definitely build a lock with c++11, just not one with data races :-) Typically a lock would involve waiting before reading (which is obviously what you're trying to avoid here) so you do not have this kind of problems.

Note that your original seqlock is buggy because you would not want to just check seq0 != seq1 (you could be in the middle of an update).  The seqlock paper has the correct condition.

Comment: None of this answers why relaxed and non-atomic loads are treated differently for memory ordering.

Comment: They're not.  What you get from the std::atomic is the "volatileness" of the underlying type.  You would get the same behavior in your 2nd case if you change your `int data` into `volatile int data`.  But this is more of a trick.  What's really in the spirit of C++11 is either use an int but with the proper memory model (seq const, very expensive so I do not recommend it) or make data an atomic with relaxed loads.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you don't need seq const, that amounts to an mfence on x86 and this code works fine using asm volatile and no mfence. (I've used it billions of times). The paper I mentioned in my other comment (hpl.hp.com/techreports/2012/HPL-2012-68.pdf) also states this is a sufficient constraint.

Comment: I am not sure what point you're making.  Using an asm volatile in this case is equivalent to the using a volatile int or using the relaxed load on the atomic, so yes I agree.  But that does not contradict what I am saying:
1) you keep an `int data`, I see no other way than using seq const which is very expensive and I do not recommend
2) you make `data` volatile, it will work but this is more of a trick
3) you use the code with the atomic and the relaxed load.

#3 is the best solution (imo).  I skimmed through the pdf, I do not see anything obvious that contradicts what I am saying

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new at reasoning about these non-sequentially-consistent memory order operations and barriers, but it could be that this code generation is correct (or rather permissible).  On the face of it, it certainly looks fishy, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's no way for a standard-conforming program to tell that the load from data was hoisted (which would mean this code is correct under the "as if" rule).

The program is reading two subsequent values from an atomic, one before the load and one after the load, and re-issuing the load whenever they don't match.  In principle, there's no reason the two atomic reads ever *have to* see different values from each other.  Even if an atomic write has just occurred, there's no way for this thread to be able to detect that it didn't read the old value again.  The thread would then go back into the loop and eventually read two consistent values from the atomic, then return, but since `seq0` and `seq1` are then discarded, the program can't tell that the value in `seq0` doesn't correspond to the value read from `data`.  Now, in principle, this also suggests to me that the entire loop could have been elided and only the load from `data` is actually necessary for correctness, but failure to elide the loop isn't necessarily a correctness issue.

If `reader()` were to return a `pair<int,unsigned>` that included `seq0` (or `seq1`) and the same hoisted loop were generated, I think it's probably incorrect code (but again I'm new to this non-sequentially-consistent operations reasoning).

Comment: I'm not sure you're quite right here. If what you're saying is true then this combination of barriers isn't enough to implement a seq-lock, which is contrary to what HP have written in this paper: http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2012/HPL-2012-68.pdf. Further you'd still expect the compiler to generate the same code for both inputs (and probably just elide the entire loop, as it does without any barriers).

Comment: @jleahy, I think that paper is not quite on point.  First, in the paper, all shared reads and writes are performed on actual `atomic`s (except in examples they indicate are incorrect), since ordinary variables are subject to the data-race constraints (no conflicting accesses) for avoiding undefined behavior.  Second, the loops they perform to mark reads and writes actually do some nontrivial calculations on the read sequence values to verify consistency, which doesn't apply in your example.  IME, either of these points is enough to render the code clearly different to an optimizer.